# Countdown Timer reset date

Tags: javascript, html

I'm try to get the following code to reset the timer after the specified date is reached so that it will restart for the following week. Please Help!!

```
<script>
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date("Aug 26, 2017 0:0:0").getTime();

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is finished, write some text
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "GAME DAY";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: After the date is reached, should the timer restart immediately?

Comment: no. So i would like would like the text to be displayed for the whole day and than it reset the following day after the specified date is reached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the if-part with this:

```
if (distance < 0) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "GAME DAY";
    if(distance < - 1000 * 60 * 60* 24){ // if its past the "game day"
        // reset timer to next week
        countDownDate += 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    }
}
```

Comment: Timer still displays game day even when the date is changed to 3 days ago.

Comment: @RaznishSmith oh yeah, i didnt notice your countDownDate is an integer. post is updated.

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thank you so much